# How to get the ip address under Windows

Tags: c, windows, ip-address, winsockets

all
i already had a "socketfd", and i was wondering how to use it to retrieve the local ip address.
under linux, i can do something like this(not exactly correct):

```
struct ifreq ifr;
ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;
ioctl(socketfd, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr);
char *address = inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr)->sin_addr);
```

but, on Windows, how can i achieve the same goal? (not using MFC)
many thanks.

edit: maybe my host has multiple ip addresses, and i want the one "connected" with "socketfd".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the socket is connected, then `getsockname()` on it will fill a `struct sockaddr` with the local name for the socket.  This works on both OSes (and anything with BSD sockets).

Answer (score 1):

```
WORD wVersionRequested;
      WSADATA wsaData;
      char name[255];
      CString ip;
      PHOSTENT hostinfo;
      wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD( 2, 0 );

      if ( WSAStartup( wVersionRequested, &wsaData ) == 0 )
      {

            if( gethostname ( name, sizeof(name)) == 0)
            {
                  if((hostinfo = gethostbyname(name)) != NULL)
                  {
                        ip = inet_ntoa (*(struct in_addr *)*hostinfo->h_addr_list);
                  }
            }

            WSACleanup( );
      }
```

with `#include <winsock2.h>`

Comment: my host has several ip addresses , and i want the one "connected" with "socketfd",so...

Comment: I tried this code and getting the following errors ...

`error: unknown type name 'CString'`

Full error and code here...
https://pastebin.com/shcZG73E