# Find IP address of the machine in C?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, ip

How do I get the IP address of the local machine in C on Windows? I was not able to get the IP address of my machine in the following code:

```
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct ifaddrs *id;
    int val;
    val = getifaddrs(&id);
    printf("Network Interface Name :- %s\n",id->ifa_name);
    printf("Network Address of %s :- %d\n",id->ifa_name,id->ifa_addr);
    printf("Network Data :- %d \n",id->ifa_data);
    printf("Socket Data : -%c\n",id->ifa_addr->sa_data);
    return 0;
}
```

I am facing an error while compiling:

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'net/if.h': No such file or directory.

I cannot use `#include <net/if.h>` as it is only available on Linux.

Comment: The code above is for Linux and similar operating systems - to do the same thing on Windows you'll need to look at MSDN to find Microsoft's equivalent API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the ip address under Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114305/how-to-get-the-ip-address-under-windows)

Comment: Maybe [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122208/get-the-ip-address-of-local-computer) helps.

Comment: swanand that question is using linux code as including net/if.h  .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code you showed does not compile because it is designed for Linux, not Windows.  There is no `<net/if.h>` header on Windows.

[`getifaddrs()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) returns a linked list of local interface addresses.  But `getifaddrs()` does not exist on Windows at all (unless you find a custom 3rd party implementation).

The equivalent on Windows is to use the Win32 [`GetAdaptersInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917.aspx) function on XP and earlier, or the [`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915.aspx) function on Vista and later.  Both functions return a linked list of detailed adapter information (much more than just addresses).

C examples are provided in their documentation on MSDN.

Answer (score -2):

The structure

```
struct ifaddrs *id;
```

is a linked list. You have to loop through it and check the existence of the address

```
if(id->fa_addr)
   // print statements
```